# Adding images dynamically to scroller

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml

i am new to flex.i am trying add images dynamically in flex using file referencei need to add images in scroller.i use this below code but adding image was not visible.can anyone help me regarding this issue pls.Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               xmlns:net="flash.net.*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.Image;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
            private var myImage:Image;
            private function OnbuttonClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
                var arr:Array = [];
                arr.push(new FileFilter("Images", ".gif;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png"));
                fileReference.browse(arr);
            }

            private function FileRefSelect(evt:Event):void {
                fileReference.load();
            }

            private function FileRefComplete(evt:Event):void {
                Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(fileReference));
                myImage             = new Image();
                //img.source = fileReference.data;

                myImage.maxWidth    = 100;
                myImage.maxHeight   = 100;
                myImage.source      = fileReference.data;
                vg.addChild(myImage);

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <net:FileReference id="fileReference"
                           select="FileRefSelect(event);"
                           complete="FileRefComplete(event);" />
    </fx:Declarations>



    <mx:ControlBar>
        <mx:Button id="btn" label="Browse Your Image"  click="OnbuttonClick(event);" />
    </mx:ControlBar>

    <s:Scroller id="scrllr" x="50" y="100" width="100" height="280" focusEnabled="false"
                hasFocusableChildren="true">
        <s:VGroup id="vg">

        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>


</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `vg.addElement(myImage);` instead of `vg.addChild(myImage);`. I am assuming you would also have got an exception mentioning the same.